# updating a model in one controller that is watched and located in a different package and used by another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Again, let me start this by thanking for your time to read this and second by apologizing for not being able to actually paste my code.. it's located on a computer that doesn't have internet access.

I am working to add an icon to a systray in a web application. The icon changes based on values contained in the model. The systray is has a controller located say

```
myproject/myjs/main/controllers/systraycontroller.js
myproject/myjs/main/models/myniftymodel.js
myproject/myjs/main/mainModule.js
```

I want to update the model based on user choices on a different page that also has a controller and it's own module

```
myproject/myjs/colors/colorsModule.js
myproject/myjs/colors/controllers/colorsController.js
```

My question, what exactly is required in colorsModule.js to get colorsController.js to be able to not only see myniftymodel.js but update it?

myniftymodel.js is just a simple model that returns a values array and is used by the DIV in systray.html to display info about the icon.

Comment: Gotta love the downvotes on this ..where has the helpful community of the old days gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you wrap the model in a service. Use one of the various providers offered by Angular.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

You can then dependency inject the service anywhere you like in your application.